# Array output to multiple lines

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ChildItem "$Folder" *.xlsx -Recurse | ?{-not ($_.PSIsContainer -or (Test-Path "I:\TEMP_Dir_SSN\$_"))} | copy-Item -Destination "I:TEMP_Dir_SSN" | out-null

Get-ChildItem "$Folder" *.xlsx -Recurse | %{
        $test = Resolve-Path $_.FullName 
        $holdArray += $test.path

}
    $holdArray | out-file "I:\TEMP_Dir_SSN\fullPath.txt" -append
```

The output:

```
I:\1992.xlsxI:\projects\confluence\projects\documents\XXXX_ComplianceRegulations.xlsxI:\projects\confluence\projects\documents\XXXX_vendorCloudStandardsPoliciesRegs.xlsx
```

I want it:

```
I:\1992.xlsx 

I:\projects\confluence\projects\documents\XXXX_ComplianceRegulations.xlsx 

I:\projects\confluence\projects\documents\XXXX_vendorCloudStandardsPoliciesRegs.xlsx
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong here. It should be adding it to the next line down, not appending it to the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$holdArray += $test.path` to `[array]$holdArray += $test.path`

You have not told PowerShell this is an array so it is treating it as a string.

Comment: @schnipdip Also an option. There, you are telling PowerShell to create an empty array before you fill it. Equally valid is: `$holdArray = @($test.path)` :-)

Comment: I like to do `$holdArray = @()` when I am working with for loops because then I just output into an array. It is visually easier for me to understand what is happening. So if something goes awry, I can understand where the problem lays. This was just forgetting to add that part hahahaha

Comment: why i love powershell: it is easy to make things happen.

Answer (score 1):

You are flattening the "array" to a space delimited string since you have not declared `$holdArray` initially. Skip the array "build" logic and use the pipeline to get the results you want.

```
Get-ChildItem $Folder *.xlsx -Recurse | 
    Resolve-Path | Convert-Path | 
    Add-Content "I:\TEMP_Dir_SSN\fullPath.txt"
```

`Add-Content` appends by default.